# Trying to experiment with data parallel Haskell - but can't get it to install

Tags: haskell, cabal, data-parallel-haskell

Is anyone using data parallel Haskell with the `2012.4.0.0 Haskell` platform?

I'm a Haskell beginner - but wanted to experiment with switching from lists to parallel arrays.

When I try and run

```
cabal install dph-examples
```

I get a build problem with `bmp.1.2.3.1`:

```
Codec\BMP.hs:208:11: Not in scope: `BSL.fromStrict'
```

Sure this is some type of version mismatch - but nor sure what to do.
Any experts out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bmp`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bmp) depends on [`bytestring`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) and [`binary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary). `binary` depends on `bytestring` itself. Your `binary` package was built with `bytestring-0.9.2.1`, the version that came with the platform.

When trying to `cabal install bmp`, `cabal` tries to install the latest version for which it can construct a valid install plan without reinstalling libraries (if possible at all). With a `binary` built with a `bytestring-0.9.2.1`, that is `bmp-1.2.3.1`, where the author forgot to bump the lower bound of the `bytestring` version, so the build fails since `fromStrict` was added in `bytestring-0.10`.

You can either install an earlier version of `bmp`,

```
cabal install "bmp < 1.2.3"
```

which is the safe option, or you can rebuild `binary` against the newer `bytestring` version. The latter likely will break some other packages depending on `binary`, so those would have to be rebuilt too. And for a package like `bytestring` which *many* other packages depend on, it would also be likely that a similar problem occurs soon again.

Comment: Thanks very much - that fixed the initial problem. Now into a world of broken dependencies of OpenGL, gloss, GLUT. Guess the problem is very few people are using this....

Comment: Uh-oh. What broke those? Did you rebuild `binary` and that broke those or what?

Comment: I must have messed up the environment in my earlier attempts to get things working. Have done a clean Haskell Platform install, followed by a 'failed' `cabal install dph-examples`, followed by your suggested `cabal install "bmp < 1.2.3"` followed by another `cabal install dph-examples` and everything look great. Thanks so much for your help Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `bytestring` >= 0.10.0.0 installed.

Comment: Cabal info bytestring tells me :- Versions installed: 0.9.2.1, 0.10.0.1